# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<axtivity>

Tags: android

I wanted to know if there is a way to save the state of an activity before starting another test case and start the next test case from this state

Answer (score 0):

If you changes to your Activity in your `setUp()` method, then all of your tests will start with those changes applied. (If you have different sets of changes to apply to your Activity, then do them in different TestCases.)